# How to show a custom validation error for a DateTimeField in the Django admin?

Tags: python, django, validation

I use a [DateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield) for one of my models. It has a [custom validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/validators/), to check, that no dates from the future will be accepted.

If I supply a date that lies in the future, the error is raised correctly but the admin shows `Bitte eine Liste mit Werten eingeben.` (`Enter a list of values.`) instead of my validation error message.

**How can I get the admin to show my own validation error message instead?**

Here are the relevant parts of my custom validator ([full source in this gist](https://gist.github.com/brutus/194e3e4399006387cd70)):

```
@deconstructible
class DateValidator():

  # …

  def __call__(self, value):
    """
    Check *value* against the stored *date*.

    If *date* is callable, it's return value is used, if not, it is used
    directly.

    """
    # get min/max date
    try:
      date = self.date()
    except TypeError:
      date = self.date
    # check
    if self.equal and value == date:
      return
    if self.after:
      if value > date:
        return
    else:
      if value < date:
        return
    raise ValidationError(
      self.message, code='invalid', params={
        'value': value.strftime(self.DATETIME_FORMAT),
        'date': date.strftime(self.DATETIME_FORMAT)
      }
    )
```

And I use it like this:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Article(models.Model):

  # …

  pub_date = models.DateTimeField(
    'Veröffentlichungsdatum', blank=True, null=True,
    validators=[DateValidator(timezone.now)],
    help_text=("…")
  )
```

Comment: Adding the relevant code to the post would help to debug, especially how you are calling the validator.

Answer (score 1):

You can raise forms.ValidationError in forms.py
Here is an example:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Are you sure you are registered? We cannot find this user.")
        return username
```

Comment: Thanks but I would rather set my validator on the model (definition). Is there no way around creating a custom form, just to show my `ValidationError`'s message?

Comment: If I havent misunderstood what you're saying: You want a custom form to show the validation error. If thats so, we've just done that. LoginForm is a custom form to only show the validation error.

Comment: That is what I rather not have to do. I created a custom validator and used it on my **model definition** (rather than in a custom form) — and it works. The problem is: in the Django admin, instead of my message from the validator, a different error message is shown, although the `ValidationError` is recognized.